# How to attach a texture to a Fixture LibGDX/Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, box2d

How to attach a texture to a Fixture LibGDX/Box2D

I have a body with two fixtures, currently I have one texture attached to one fixture, how would I get another texture attached to the other fixture. Currently I have the other texture in a separate class but I can't figure out a way to get the texture attached to the second fixture.

This is the class with that creates the body, the two fixtures and the texture:

```
public isaac(World world, playScreen screen){
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("isaac_body"));
    this.world = world;

    currentState = State.STANDING;
    previousState = State.STANDING;
    stateTimer = 0;
    walkingRight = true;
    walkingDown = true;

    Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    for(int i = 6; i < 8; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i*32, 0, 32, 32));
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i*32, 32, 32, 32));
    isaacWalkY = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.1f,frames);
    frames.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 64, 32, 32));
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 96, 32, 32));
    isaacWalkX = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.1f, frames);

    isaacStand = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 0,32, 32, 32);

    isaacDefault = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 0, 0, 32, 32);



    defineIsaac();
    setBounds(0,0,28 / icsGame.PPM, 28 / icsGame.PPM);
    setRegion(isaacStand);

}

public void update(float dt){
    setPosition(b2Body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2Body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
    setRegion(getFrame(dt));

}

public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt){
    currentState = getState();

    TextureRegion region;
    switch(currentState){
        case WALKINGY:
            region = isaacWalkY.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case WALKINGX:
            region = isaacWalkX.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case STANDING:
        default:
            region = isaacStand;
            break;
    }

    if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0 || !walkingRight) && !region.isFlipX()){
        region.flip(true, false);
        walkingRight = false;
    }
    else if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0 || walkingRight) && region.isFlipX()){
        region.flip(true, false);
        walkingRight = true;
    }

    if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y > 0) && !region.isFlipY()){
        region.flip(false, true);
        walkingDown = false;
    }
    else if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y < 0) && region.isFlipY()){
        region.flip(false, true);
        walkingDown = true;
    }

    stateTimer = currentState == previousState ? stateTimer + dt : 0;
    previousState = currentState;

    return region;

}

public State getState(){
    if(b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y > 0 || b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y < 0){
        return State.WALKINGY;
    }
    else if((b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x > 0 || b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x < 0)){
        return State.WALKINGX;
    }
    else{
        return State.STANDING;
    }
}

public void defineIsaac(){
    BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
    bdef.position.set(64 / icsGame.PPM, 64 / icsGame.PPM);
    bdef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    b2Body = world.createBody(bdef);

    FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(4 / icsGame.PPM);

    fdef.shape = shape;
    b2Body.createFixture(fdef).setUserData("body");

    FixtureDef fdef2 = new FixtureDef();
    shape2 = new CircleShape();
    shape2.setRadius(10 / icsGame.PPM);
    Vector2 vec = new Vector2(shape.getPosition().x / 2, shape2.getRadius());

    shape2.setPosition(vec);

    fdef2.shape = shape2;
    b2Body.createFixture(fdef2);
}

}
```

This is the class that creates the head:

```
public class isaacHead extends Sprite {
public enum State {EASTWEST, NORTH, SOUTH, DEFAULT}

public State currentState;
public State previousState;
public World world;
public Body b2Head;
private TextureRegion isaacDefault;
private Animation<TextureRegion> eastWest;
private Animation<TextureRegion> north;
private Animation<TextureRegion> south;
private float stateTimer;
private boolean shootingRight;
private isaac player;


public isaacHead(World world, playScreen screen) {
    super(screen.getAtlas().findRegion("isaac_body"));
    this.world = world;

    currentState = State.DEFAULT;
    previousState = State.DEFAULT;
    stateTimer = 0;

    Array<TextureRegion> frames = new Array<TextureRegion>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 0, 32, 32));
    south = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.15f, frames);
    frames.clear();

    for (int i = 2; i < 4; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 0, 32, 32));
    eastWest = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.15f, frames);
    frames.clear();

    for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++)
        frames.add(new TextureRegion(getTexture(), i * 32, 0, 32, 32));
    north = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.15f, frames);

    isaacDefault = new TextureRegion(getTexture(), 0, 0, 32, 32);

    setBounds(0, 0, 32 / icsGame.PPM, 32 / icsGame.PPM);
    setRegion(isaacDefault);


}

public void update(float dt) {
    setRegion(getFrame(dt));
}

public TextureRegion getFrame(float dt) {
    currentState = getState();

    TextureRegion region;
    switch (currentState) {
        case SOUTH:
            region = south.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case EASTWEST:
            region = eastWest.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case NORTH:
            region = north.getKeyFrame(stateTimer, true);
            break;
        case DEFAULT:
        default:
            region = isaacDefault;
            break;
    }

    if (((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) || !shootingRight) && !region.isFlipX())) {
        region.flip(true, false);
        shootingRight = false;
    } else if (((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) || shootingRight) && region.isFlipX())) {
        region.flip(true, false);
        shootingRight = true;
    }

    stateTimer = currentState == previousState ? stateTimer + dt : 0;
    previousState = currentState;

    return region;
}

public State getState() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        return State.NORTH;
    } else if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) || (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT))) {
        return State.EASTWEST;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
        return State.SOUTH;
    } else {
        return State.DEFAULT;
    }
}

}
```

And this is the class that the textures are drawn in, currently I am setting the position of the second texture in this class but it only runs that command once and it does not attach it to the second fixture:

```
public class playScreen implements Screen {
private icsGame game;
private TextureAtlas atlas;

private OrthographicCamera gameCam;
private Viewport gamePort;
private Scenes.hud hud;

private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2dr;

private isaac player;
private isaacHead head;

public playScreen(icsGame game) {
    atlas = new TextureAtlas("isaac.pack");

    this.game = game;
    gameCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    gamePort = new FitViewport(icsGame.V_WIDTH / icsGame.PPM,icsGame.V_HEIGHT / icsGame.PPM,gameCam);
    hud = new hud(game.batch);

    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("Level1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / icsGame.PPM);
    gameCam.position.set(gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2, gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0), true);
    b2dr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    new b2WorldCreator(world, map);

    player = new isaac(world, this);
    head = new isaacHead(world, this);

    world.setContactListener(new worldContactListener());

}

public TextureAtlas getAtlas(){
    return atlas;
}

@Override
public void show() {
}

public void handleInput(float dt){
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -2) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(-1.5f,0f);
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(1.5f,0f);
        } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) == Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0, 0);
        }
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0,1.5f);
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y >= -2)
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(0,-1.5f);
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(-1.5f, -1.5f);
        }
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(1.5f, -1.5f);
        }
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(-1.5f, 1.5f);
        }
        if ((Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) && (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2) && (player.b2Body.getLinearVelocity().y <= 2)) {
            player.b2Body.setLinearVelocity(1.5f, 1.5f);
        }

}

public void update(float dt){
    handleInput(dt);

    world.step(1/60f,6,2);

    head.setPosition(player.shape2.getPosition().x+1, player.shape2.getPosition().y+1);

    player.update(dt);
    head.update(dt);

    gameCam.update();
    renderer.setView(gameCam);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render();

    b2dr.render(world, gameCam.combined);

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
    game.batch.begin();
    player.draw(game.batch);
    head.draw(game.batch);
    game.batch.end();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(hud.stage.getCamera().combined);
    hud.stage.draw();
}
```

Comment: I have one question, why are you creating the head and the player separated? For me should be easier create a texture only for the player + head in all positions UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT and STAND, so you don't need to sync everything all the time with the b2body.